# How to design a form for accessibility using ARIA?

Tags: forms, accessibility

I'm redesigning an application form and want to make sure it is as accessible as possible. I'm not an expert in accessibility by any means, but I am trying to mark up the design for developers to code. Am I using the labels correctly?

1. Should the box for **role="form" aria-label="primary contact"** include the **Primary Contact** and **description sentence**, or just the entry fields?
2. The **Designated Signee** question is dynamic. Selecting **Same as Primary Contact** results in the fields below being hidden. What is the correct naming convention for the radio group and what should the orange box cover?
3. Any tips for what I should label the headings "Primary Contact" and "Designated Signee" to make it easier for the developers? Do they need id="xxx" tags?

[image]

Comment: There are too many questions and in the current form it boils down to a site review. Can you adjust it so that it is a single question that focuses on a wider accessibility problem?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your front end developers should take the decision to choose the appropriate HTML or ARIA semantics. There is the risk that, if you don't have enough technical preparation, you could mess or overcomplicate things for a screen reader user. Focus on an inclusive experience design and share the duty of the accessibility implementation with the rest of your team (FE, PM, QA)